# How to rewrite URLs split by hyphens?

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I am getting confused while writing URLs with hyphens. It is conflicting with GET parameters.

For instance, I have a long book name in URL, with spaces replaced by hyphens, like `the-famous-world-records-of-athletics`. After this I am getting error in pagination also separated with hyphens.

Please suggest how I can write URLs in given stage:

```
example.com/vc.php?book=the-famous-world-records-of-athletics

example.com/vc.php?book=the-famous-world-records-of-athletics&page=1

example.com/vc.php?book=the-famous-world-records-of-athleticstopic=jumping-and-racing&page=2
```

Wishing to write as:

```
example.com/the-famous-world-records-of-athletics.html

example.com/the-famous-world-records-of-athletics-1.html

example.com/the-famous-world-records-of-athletics-jumping-and-racing-2.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minus is perfectly valid in an URL, it is a so-called 'unreserved' character.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

If you really need to replace them, I'd replace them with `%2D`, just like you would replace a space with `%20`.